# How to make Jetbrains editors make use of JDK 6 on Windows?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

I am running Windows for the first time in several years and of course I installed Java 8 to make use of Jetbraisn IDEs. The problem however, is that the font rendering in Java 8 on all systems seems to suck so I installed JDK 1.6 because I know it is much better.

I tried to understand this guide: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under and while I completely know how to do this on the Mac or Linux I am completely lost in the Windows world.

Could someone guide me trough on how I can make use of JDK 1.6 for running their products on a Windows machine? My java installation is: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45`

Comment: What is your `JAVA_HOME` set to?

Comment: Not sure @vikingsteve how can I check environment variables on windows? I don't find it when I go under computer settings and the normal way to find the path env variable.

Comment: Easiest way mate is to run `cmd.exe` to get a command prompt -> thereafter type `set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome "back" to windows :)

The jetbrains guide you linked to specifies very many specific settings that can override the JDK for various jetbrains products. If you notice the last one, `JAVA_HOME` that's the most general way of setting the JDK for almost all the java programs on your pc that aren't bundled with their own.

Given you don't override any of the other settings, and that 1.6 is acceptable as the default JDK for other applications on your windows pc, I think you just need to change JAVA_HOME.

You can change your `JAVA_HOME` back to 1.6 here:

Windows button -> right click My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced Settings -> Environment Vars -> edit JAVA_HOME under System variables.

Then restart intelliJ, that should do it.

Comment: Thanks, I set the JAVA_HOME to my 1.6 installation directory and added %JAVA_HOME%/bin to the path variable, but the fonts still look crappy: http://piclair.com/data/6bv81.jpg They do not look as "soft" as on OSX but that's maybe how it should look like on Windows?

Comment: I guess the fonts are not going to look exactly the same, but there is some aliasing issues in the screenshot you showed. Maybe you can try increasing the size a bit via control-mouse scroll up?

Comment: I did increase the font size, but it still look like crap. Gah, stuff like this among other things really makes me want to afford a new Mac Pro. Even if this is Java Swings (and Jetbrains for using it) fault.